# How can i find a file in a hard

Tags: c#

How can i find a file that stored in specific folder in a hard drive?

For example, I have file named `171_s.JPG`

I need to find the file by its partial name, i.e. `171_s`.

Any idea how can i implement this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx). For example, to search the entire hard disk with the label `C`:

```
var matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "171_s*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

or if you know the specific directory and only want to search that directory:

```
var matches = Directory.GetFiles(path, "171_s*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search a specific directory using the GetFiles method:

```
string directory=@"C:\temp";
string searchParams =@"171_s*";

foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory,searchParams))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\",
                               "171_s*", 
                               SearchOptions.AllDirectories);
```